# Algorithm to Check All Permutations of Slot Machine For Win

Tags: algorithm

I have a program that has a slot machine with 5 columns and 5 images in each. I'm trying to find an efficient algorithm that can check all the permutations for several combinations that would indicate a win. Those combinations are: 2 pair of matching images, 3 of the same image, 4 of the same image, 5 of the same image, and finally 3 of the same image and 2 of the same image different from the first 3. I'm not concerned with order. Thanks for any tips or suggestions.

Comment: This is actually almost identical to computing poker hands for a 5-card hand (one pair, two pair, three of a kind, four of a kind, full house...).  Just to help you broaden your search terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a dictionary / hashmap:

```
counts = {}
foreach image in row:
     // TODO: If the image is not already in the dictionary, add it.
    counts[image] += 1
```

Then you can check how many of each image you have by iterating over the values in the dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

You could also have some sort of Dictionary or Hashtable datastructure (key/value pairs) with 5 elements. As you enumerate each column, add +1 to the value (the image, or as Mark Byers says, something that "uniquely identifies them," will be the key). Then sort your key/value datastructure. You can then create an FSM with your logic above to classify the winnings.

Comment: +1 : I changed my answer to almost exactly this almost the same time as you posted your answer. First I was assuming it was some low level C code without such a datastructure but to be frank if that's the case he should make that clear.